# Delete user created with --disabled-password option

Tags: user-management

I've just created this user (without pwd)

```
sudo adduser --home /opt/nexus --disabled-login --disabled-password nexus
```

now I am trying to delete the user using

```
sudo userdel -r nexus
[sudo] password for nexus:
```

but since the user has no password I am stuck

Comment: BTW: Ubuntu 12.10 is way EOL. Why don't you upgrade to a newer, supported version?

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to use `sudo` from a user account without a password and without sudo privileges. This won't work.

You need to login with a different account and run your command from there.

Comment: in order to delete nexus user ?

Comment: Does the account you're logged into have sudo privileges? If yes, then use *your own* password for sudo, not the nexus user's password. (That's how sudo works!). If your current account does not have sudo privileges, you'll need to use a different account.